# How to add some non-standard font to Html?

Tags: html, css, fonts, hyperlink

So i wanted to add a custom font to my Html and CSS but i'm struggling to link the Html my font.

```
    style type="text/css">
@font-face {
    font-family: "Uni Sans";
    src: local(unisans) format("woff");
}
p.unisans { 
    font-family: "Uni Sans", Verdana, Tahoma;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Please elaborate on the actual and expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot link a local font to your html or CSS. You need to convert the font you want to webfont, like Fontsquirrel. Download and unzip the files, place them into the folder of your html page or a new "fonts" folder located in the same folder as your html or CSS file. Then open the stylesheet.css that you get from Fontsquirrel, copy and paste the CSS of the font into your new css file and change the path of the font as you need.
Then use the font 'name' in your CSS wherever you need.

Comment: I did all the steps but it still doesn't work  <style type="text/css">
@font-face {
    font-family: 'uni_sansthin_caps';
    src: url('/projekt/uni_sans_thin-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('/projekt/uni_sans_thin-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

Comment: Can you please add your CSS and html, or send a link online so I can help? It might be that your paths are not correct or it's not working localy and you have to upload the files to ftp.

Comment: i figured it out now, the problem was that i didn't link stylesheet.css to my hmtl. Thank you so much, it helped me

Comment: I am glad you found the bug :)

Answer (score 1):

use [Font Squirrel generator](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator). But beware of the font license!