# Font present In PC can be used in Online sites?

Tags: html, css, fonts, styling, editing

Actually, I have downloaded a font in my PC and now i want to use that font in my site online. Is it possible to do so, if yes then how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to embed fonts in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220236/how-to-embed-fonts-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you put the font file (.ttf) in a folder and reference it in the src:url and path it correctly

```
@font-face {
    font-family: fontName;
    src: url(font/fontName.ttf);
}

body {
    font-family: fontName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've answered that before here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44611769/3362989

Please check about font license, you cannot use every font you have on your PC for web.